# Using webots to build a swarm of robots

Tags: webots

In webots, is there any way to find the number of neighboring robots, to a given robot in any given radius?
An algorithm I am implementing requires a list of neighboring robots.
I got an idea that uses emitters and receivers.
So, the idea was
each robot sends out a broadcast with a message containing it's respective ID, within a given range and each robot also has a receiver.
Then each robot will receive the messages and store the ID's in a list which is the required list.
but this would include a lot emitting and receiving.
I want to know if there is an easier way to get the required list.

Answer (score 1):

You can "cheat" with the Supervisor functionalities. With the Supervisor robot, you can get the position of each robot in the world and determine whether a robot is in the radius or not.

Please refer to the following page:
https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor